# Question about come across and synonyms of it

Tags: meaning

I wanted to ask if "Come across" could be a synonym of "looks". According to the cambridge dictionary come across is: To behave in a way that makes people believe that you have a particular characteristic". Thanks

PS: Here are some examples
1."She comes across really well (= creates a positive image) on television."
2."He comes across as a bit of a bore in interview."

Answer (score 0):

The word "looks" refers only to visual aspects of the perception of a person.

The way a person "comes across" can be communicated by looks, by voice , by behaviour, and conceivably by touch, taste or smell.

So

> "She looks very interested in people, but when you can hear her talking she comes across as self-absorbed".

Comment: Yes, I think it refers specifically to how the character of the person is expressed as a whole - by what they say, their clothes, body language ... everything one experiences, even subconciously!

Answer (score 0):

And there is an idiom for it: [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+across+as+(someone+or+something))

**come across as (someone or something)**

> To be viewed by others in a particular way; to have one's personality,
>   behavior, intentions, etc., interpreted in a particular way.

Synonyms?  *convey* and *project*.